# facebook logout API

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm using the Manual Login Flow from facebook to login users to my site. This means, redirecting them to accept the app, and the getting their info. (my app is also physical, ==> one browser for many people)

I got it working as I wanted, however, as they are only redirected to login, they are kept logged-in at browser-level, meaning that if another user comes after them and tries to login, they will only be shown the other person's profile, or be redirected as if they logged in.

Thus, I need a log-out method at browser-level, but I can't find any links, or api to logout a user from the browser.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks!

Comment: _“one browser for many people”_ – that is not a good idea for a Facebook app; it is likely that FB’s security system will find a lot of users logging in on one device suspicious – can lead from hassle for your user (having to confirm extra steps), up until a block of the app.

Comment: Anyway, you can log a user out of Facebook, as long as you have a valid access token for them. The PHP SDK has methods to create a logout URL – so you can go look it up there, what the exact URL is and what parameters need to be passed.